# XML Parse - Loop through different nodes and output as one

Tags: xml

I have an XML as seen here:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MIFORMS_EXPORT>
  <SESSION FORM_ID="775938" CID="" ID="HAKKI-LAPTOP_634975758376381105">
    <FIELD NAME="A001DATE_M" Y="2.32" X="5.5" WIDTH="7.15" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="A002" Y="2.32" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="A003" Y="1.11" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="A004" Y="1.11" X="5.5" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR01" Y="7.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR02" Y="8.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR03" Y="9.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR04" Y="10.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR05" Y="11.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR06" Y="12.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR07" Y="13.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR08" Y="14.02" X="17" WIDTH="2.21" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="OR99" Y="16.52" X="17.5" WIDTH="1.59" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="DESCRIPTOR" Y="25" X="17.5" WIDTH="2" HEIGHT="0.5" />
    <FIELD NAME="A001DATE_M_2" Y="2.32" X="5.5" WIDTH="7.15" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="A002_2" Y="2.32" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="A003_2" Y="1.11" X="17.83" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="A004_2" Y="1.11" X="5.5" WIDTH="2.38" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA101" Y="8" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA102" Y="8.7" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA103" Y="9.42" X="5.01" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA104" Y="10.12" X="5.01" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA105" Y="10.82" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA106" Y="11.51" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA107" Y="12.21" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA108" Y="12.91" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA109" Y="13.63" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA110" Y="14.35" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA111" Y="15.07" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA112" Y="15.77" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA113" Y="16.47" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA114" Y="17.18" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA115" Y="17.93" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA116" Y="18.65" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA117" Y="19.38" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA118" Y="20.08" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA119" Y="20.79" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA120" Y="21.5" X="5.01" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA121" Y="22.21" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA122" Y="22.96" X="5.01" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA123" Y="23.66" X="5.01" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA124" Y="24.38" X="5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA201" Y="8.01" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA202" Y="8.71" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA203" Y="9.42" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA204" Y="10.12" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA205" Y="10.82" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA206" Y="11.51" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA207" Y="12.21" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA208" Y="12.91" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA209" Y="13.63" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA210" Y="14.35" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA211" Y="15.07" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA212" Y="15.77" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA213" Y="16.47" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA214" TIMESTAMP="02/27/2013 15:30:43" Y="17.18" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6">1</FIELD>
    <FIELD NAME="WTA215" Y="17.93" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA216" Y="18.65" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA217" Y="19.38" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA218" Y="20.08" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA219" Y="20.8" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA220" Y="21.5" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA221" Y="22.21" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA222" Y="22.97" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA223" Y="23.67" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA224" Y="24.38" X="11.5" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA301" Y="8.01" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA302" Y="8.71" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA303" Y="9.42" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA304" Y="10.12" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA305" Y="10.82" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA306" Y="11.51" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA307" Y="12.21" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA308" Y="12.91" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA309" Y="13.63" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA310" Y="14.35" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA311" Y="15.07" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA312" Y="15.77" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA313" Y="16.47" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA314" Y="17.18" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA315" Y="17.93" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA316" Y="18.65" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA317" Y="19.38" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA318" Y="20.08" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA319" Y="20.8" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA320" Y="21.5" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA321" Y="22.21" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA322" Y="22.97" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA323" Y="23.67" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA324" Y="24.38" X="18" WIDTH="2.22" HEIGHT="0.6" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA996" Y="25.8" X="3.21" WIDTH="1.59" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA997" Y="25.81" X="8.2" WIDTH="1.59" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA999" Y="25.81" X="18.19" WIDTH="1.59" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <FIELD NAME="WTA998" Y="25.81" X="13.2" WIDTH="1.59" HEIGHT="0.99" />
    <IMAGE NAME="NewImagemap" TYPE="PAGE" FORMAT="image/png" RESOLUTION="28.35" DEPTH="24">775938-0-02272013-153112426-HAKKI-LAPTOP_634975758376381105.png</IMAGE>
    <IMAGE NAME="NewImagemap" TYPE="PAGE" FORMAT="image/png" RESOLUTION="28.35" DEPTH="24">775938-1-02272013-153112504-HAKKI-LAPTOP_634975758376381105.png</IMAGE>
    <IMAGE NAME="NewImagemap" TYPE="PAGE" FORMAT="image/png" RESOLUTION="28.35" DEPTH="24">775938-2-02272013-153112582-HAKKI-LAPTOP_634975758376381105.png</IMAGE>
  </SESSION>
</MIFORMS_EXPORT>
```

I want to loop through the FIELD elements and value and also IMAGE Name and Resolution.

I am using C# and have devised this code:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(ea.Result);
    var list = from p in doc.Descendants("FIELD")
               select new ExportData
                   {
                       Height = (string) p.Attribute("HEIGHT"),
                       Width = (string) p.Attribute("WIDTH"),
                       X = (string) p.Attribute("X"),
                       Y = (string) p.Attribute("Y"),
                       ID = (string) p.Attribute("NAME"),
                       Value = p.Value,
                       Image = (from c in doc.Descendants("IMAGE") select c.Value).FirstOrDefault(),
                       Resolution = (from c in doc.Descendants("IMAGE") select c.Attribute("RESOLUTION").Value).FirstOrDefault()
                   };

var enumerable = list as ExportData[] ?? list.ToArray();

foreach (var data in enumerable)
                                {
//output
}
```

This makes FIELD work fine and I get all the information I need from there. However for IMAGE the same c.Value comes up over and over.

How do I loop through FIELD while looping through IMAGE.Value as well?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I did not understand what you want, for each field you want all three images?

Comment: It didn't make sense because I was really confused at the time.

Comment: What we are doing now is parsing Image separately and using an ID in the name to know what page it is referencing. Sorry for the confusing question and thanks for trying to help.